# Using @variable within link_to in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to make

```
<%= link_to @company.name, current_company %>
```

work. It does work, as long as I stay within the same profile page. As soon as I'm trying to leave it, I get the **NoMethodError in StaticPages#about - undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass**. I understand the problem lies within the controller (I guess?), but that's it. Can anybody point me in the right direction please.

**UPDATED**

Updating methods in my satic_pages controller to

```
  def home
    @company = Company.new
  end

  def about
    @company = Company.new
  end
```

helps with skipping the error, but instead of the company name the links start to look like

```
/companies/2
```

Comment: I submitted an answer, but if you post your controller, it would be helpful to debug this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Since you want your link to simply display the company name, you can just do something like `<%= link_to @company.name, @company%>`

In your controller, you want to reference which company you're linking to, so you can do something like `@company = Company.last`. This would take the last record that you created. Now, when you load your page, the link should take you to the show page for that company with the last company's name as the text for the hyperlink.

Comment: Do I have to initialise @company = Company.new for every single action in the controller then? I have like 5 pages, and that doesn't seem like a true Rails way

Comment: No, you would only need to initialize `@company` when you have a form for it or you need a new `Company` record. If you wanted to update an old record, you can do something like `@company = Company.find(1)` or something similar.

Comment: I just want the name of the company to be visible as a link_to Title throughout every single page on all controllers.

Comment: @DenisGrammakov I am also confused as to what you're trying to do. From your updated answer, it looks like you want to change the way the url is displayed. I'd suggest looking into FriendlyId (http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid)

Comment: @DenisGrammakov I updated my answer. I got the link_to arguments mixed up. The new link_to line should work. Let me know if you run into any problem.